# Remove ActionBar in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I have some troubles trying to remove a toolbar in a specific fragment, i have this code in onCreateView fragment method:

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login,container,false);
    mValidator = new Validator(this);
    mValidator.setValidationListener(this);
    mFbHelper = new 
    mGHelper = new GoogleHelper(this, null, this);

    ((DrawerUtil) getActivity()).setDrawerLocked(true);
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();
    initViews(view);
    return view;
}
```

I can hide the ActionBar, but the idea is to remove the ActionBar to use properly a logo, im using this code: `((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(state);`
 but it doesnt work.[image]
Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, but in specific fragment

Comment: check my edited answer.....

Answer (score 5):

For a specific fragment you can use :

```
override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar!!.hide()
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar!!.show()
    }


    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar!!.hide()
    }
```

Comment: Best answer. This shows and hides actionbar for specific Fragment.

Answer (score 4):

Try like this

```
private HomeActivity csActivity;
```

and

```
csActivity      = (HomeActivity)getActivity();
csActivity.getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

Comment: Actually i can hide the actionbar, the idea is to remove it from the specific fragment

Comment: what is the difference in both

Comment: removing one you can add other custom

Answer (score 1):

For your login activity use

```
<style name="BaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
   <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
   <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

this will remove the default ActionBar provided by android.So attach your fragment to this activity and there will be no action bar in your fragment too.

For other activities if you need a ActionBar you can use the same theme and add Toolbar as actionBar to youer activity.

If you do not want ActionBar use theme

```
parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
```

If you want ActionBar use theme

```
parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" or

parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dark.LightActionBar"
```

If you use light or dark ActionBar theme you will get a default ActionBar.Again if you want to hide this u can do this

```
getActivity().getSupportActionBar().hide();    // in Fragment

getSupportActionBar().hide();                  // in Activity
```

Answer (score 1):

for kotlin,
using

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
```

Try

```
 override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        //hide action bar from splash screen
        (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar!!.hide()
 }
```

in the specific fragment(s, and

```
            supportActionBar!!.hide()
```

in the Activity/Activities.

Note: do not forget to replace "hide()" by "show()" when you want the ActionBar to be visible again.

Answer (score 0):

An activity in which your load your fragment ,try below code in java file;

```
 ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
 actionBar.hide();
```

and remove below line from Menifest .xml

```
 android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
```

Comment: Nope, actually i have this  NoActionBar in the Manifest file, and also is a fragment

Comment: I change my answer..Try that

Comment: I think the problem with this is that if you have multiple fragments it will also not show to all those fragments.

Answer (score 0):

you can remove it from xml file,check your activity code where fragment is loading and make changes there if this fragment is load than toolbar.setvisibility to gone

Comment: im not calling the getSupportActionBar in the fragment_login.xml

Comment: Post your activity code from which u r loading your fragment

Comment: not needed , you want to do in all fragment? or only one

Comment: Only one @jigar savaliya

Comment: Only one @jigar savaliya

Comment: see edit  and if you not understand than plz provide your activity where frgmnt is loading

Answer (score 0):

It may be a little late, but this may save the next OP some minutes of searching. This is what worked for me @Johan Sanchez . Assuming that you have declared the theme to `NoActionBar` in your manifest but a blank space remains, its probably your XML files..

In my `main_activity.xml` file is a fragment placeholder that will be replaced by the respective fragment xml files... inside it is a layout_margintop attribute. Remove it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="simiyu.com.smallheaven.MainActivity">
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/flContent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The result should then be as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="simiyu.com.smallheaven.MainActivity">
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/flContent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
enter code here
```